# Angular 2 Bind Selected Attribute to Dynamically Created Options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular

I'm using Angular 2 RC4.

I create a dropdown select element which is bound to a variable in my component and create the options for this select using `*ngFor`, like this:

```
<select id="role-select" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="foo.bars" multiple>
    <option *ngFor="let bar of bars">{{bars}}</option>
</select>
```

The `bars` variable is dynamically populated:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this._service.GetBars().subscribe(
        result => {
            this.bars = result;
        },
        err => {
            console.log(err);
        },
        () => {}  
    );
}
```

I also dynamically populate the `foo.bars` variable:

```
constructor(public _service: Service){
    _service.GetFooBars()
        .subscribe((data) => {
            this.foo.bars = data;
        },(err) => {
            console.log(err);
        },  () => {
            // done                    
        });
}
```

Now what I want to do is to set the `selected` attribute to true on any options that match the `bars` in `foo.bars`.
Currently I use this:

```
var roleSelect = document.getElementById("role-select");
this.foo.bars.forEach((v,i) => {
    for (var j = 0; j < roleSelect.options.length; j++) {
        if (roleSelect.options[j].text === v) {
            roleSelect.options[j].selected = true;
        }
    }
});
```

This works perfectly fine, but the transpiler throws errors saying options does not exist on HTMLElement[] and I would like a slightly more robust solution.

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about

```
ngOnInit(){
    this._service.GetBars().contactMap(result => {
        this.bars = result;
        return this._service.GetFooBars();
    }).subscribe(
        data => {
            this.foo.bars = data;
            setSelected();
        },
        err => console.log(err)
        )
}

setSelected(){
    var roleSelect = document.getElementById("role-select");
    this.foo.bars.forEach((v, i) => {
        for (var j = 0; j < roleSelect.options.length; j++) {
            if (roleSelect.options[j].text === v) {
                roleSelect.options[j].selected = true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

however, I think you don't really need setSelected function.

In theory, ngModel should take care of that.

if not, in your template, you can add `[selected]="bar===foo.bars"`

```
<select id="role-select" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="foo.bars" multiple>
    <option *ngFor="let bar of bars" [selected]="bar===foo.bars">{{bars}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: nope, i'll still get the transpiler errors. and `foo.bars` is an array so a simple comparison of a string and an array isn't going to give me the required result. however, i'd be curious to know if ngModel does take care of this

Comment: try to make a plunker so people can help you easier. I didn't test my code but it should work. I can see the first solution probably still cause the same issue, did you try the template solution ?

Comment: so you fix it ? how ?

Comment: `[(ngModel)]` was already doing it, it just wasn't showing it visually